# jQuery slideshow doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have this [website](http://www.boogie.co.il) and from today the picture slide show (using jQuery) stopped working on Firefox. Working fine on IE & Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: works for me (v3.6.3), edit: on v3.6.6 works either.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in javascript?